# Using tcomb, am I missing something or is it not possible to define an instance function?

Tags: javascript, tcomb

I am trying to use `tcomb` and failing at the moment because I cannot wrap my head around how to define an instance function.

Say I have a type:

```
t.struct({
  year: t.Integer,
  monthIndex: t.Integer,
  dayIndex: t.maybe(t.Integer),
  indexInMonth: t.maybe(t.Integer),
  title: t.Str,
  subtitle: t.maybe(t.Str),
  description: t.maybe(t.Str),
  iconIdentifier: t.maybe(t.Str),
})
```

so far so good.

#### The problem

Now let's say I want to add a `month` **instance** method that can read `this` and get the right month name:

```
month() {
  return MonthsInYear[this.monthIndex]
},
```

If I try adding that to the interior of the above, it just doesn't see it.

```
const b1 = CalEvent({
  year: 2015,
  monthIndex:2,
  title: 'abc',
  description: 'abc'
})

console.log(b1.month)
```

The same happens if I try to do `mixin` or really anything other than  *defining the function every single time*.

I originally had the `of` syntax in there as with the function `compare` below...

```
t.struct({
  year: t.Integer,
  monthIndex: t.Integer,
  compare: t.func([CalEvent], CalEventComparisonResult).of(
    (toCompare) => CalEvent(compare(this,toCompare))
  ),
  dayIndex: t.maybe(t.Integer),
  indexInMonth: t.maybe(t.Integer),
  title: t.Str,
  subtitle: t.maybe(t.Str),
  description: t.maybe(t.Str),
  iconIdentifier: t.maybe(t.Str),
})
```

Still no dice.

I am beginning to think that what I want to do cannot be done within `tcomb`. And if that is the case I will be shocked that such a basic capability is not included...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [README](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb)

```
const Person = t.struct({
  name: t.String,              // required string
  surname: t.maybe(t.String),  // optional string
  age: Integer,                // required integer
  tags: t.list(t.String)       // a list of strings
}, 'Person');

// methods are defined as usual
Person.prototype.getFullName = function () {
  return `${this.name} ${this.surname}`;
};
```